# My Maven Module isn't generating a JAR

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I have the following hierarchy:

```
my-app
  \__ pom.xml
  \__ jar-module
        \__ pom.xml
  \__ webapp-module
        \__ pom.xml
  \__ core-module
        \__ pom.xml
```

Where `core-module` acts as a library providing common code for `webapp-module` and `jar-module`.

`webapp-module` works just fine, it's generating a `war` as expected and the code from `core-module` is being used.

The problem is with `jar-module`. I have no idea why, but `jar-module` isn't outputting a `jar`, even when I select to run (in IntelliJ IDEA) a simple `main` with a `println()` it does run, but there's no `jar` on the `target` folder.

**How can I solve this and make the `jar-module` output a `jar`?**

I am not very experienced with `Maven`, my goal is to be able to use the same `Jersey` code on a local `Glassfish` and in a `jar` to be deployed at [`AWS Lambda Serverless Java Container`](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container) so I can easily test it locally before deployment.

I would appreciate any corrections on my hierarchy and on `pom` errors as well.

`my-app` `pom.xml` has a `packaging` of `pom`, but `core-module` and `jar-module` have a `packaging` of `jar` and `webapp-module` has a `packaging` of `war`.

here are the `POM`s:

**my-app POM**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>core-module</module>
    </modules>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**core-module POM:**
(I also tried it with `<packaging>pom</packaging>` and no `jar skip` properties, it didn't work)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example.myapp</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>webservice-core</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>../jar-module</module>
        <module>../webapp-module</module>
    </modules>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.deploy.skip>true</maven.deploy.skip>
        <jar.skipIfEmpty>true</jar.skipIfEmpty>
        <maven.install.skip>true</maven.install.skip>
        <javax-ws-rs-version.version>2.1</javax-ws-rs-version.version>
        <jersey.version>2.26</jersey.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax-ws-rs-version.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**webapp-module POM:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>core-module</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example.myapp</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>webapp-module</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>webapp Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <jersey.version>2.26</jersey.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>core-module</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.example.myapp</groupId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>webapp</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

**jar-module POM:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>core-module</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example.myapp</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>jar-module</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <jersey.version>2.26</jersey.version>
        <maven-shade-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-shade-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>core-module</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.example.myapp</groupId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-jersey</artifactId>
            <version>0.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-shade-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

my-app is your parent module and rest are child so provide a dependencies order in parent project pom so that when you build the project ,maven will provide the dependencies as you provided in parent module.

```
<modules>
    <module>core-module</module>
</modules>
```

Provide the proper ordering like parent and child modules to understand the maven for building.

Answer (score 0):

my-app

```
<modules>
    <module>core-module</module>
    <module>jar-module</module>
    <module>web-module</module>
</modules>
```

core-module

```
no <modules>
```

This is a clean hierarchy, mirrored by the directory hierarchy.

There is a difference between `module`s and there container and the `parent` relation, and other subtleties. So *maybe* this helps.

Comment: I think that's the setup I had at first, and it wasn't generating a jar as well... But I will test it again later... It's pretty late in here, I just need to get some sleep before I try it

Comment: I found the error, I am using IntelliJ IDEA, there's a special "Maven Projects" window that has to be used to `package` the artifacts.